# How can I obtain a relative time string with a three-letter month?

Tags: android, android-dateutils

I am using this code to get a relative time in my app:

```
DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
        mReferenceTime,
        now,
        DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS,
        DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE
);
```

It is returning everything correctly, but I want to shorten the month. For example, in place of "December 21" it should instead return "Dec 21". How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the flag `DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_MONTH`. From the Android [source code (lines 781-782)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/format/DateUtils.java):

"If `FORMAT_ABBREV_MONTH` is set, then the month (if shown) is abbreviated to a 3-letter string."

Look at the three-parameter version of `getRelativeTimeSpanString`:

```
public static CharSequence getRelativeTimeSpanString(long time, long now, long minResolution) {
    int flags = FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR | FORMAT_ABBREV_MONTH;
    return getRelativeTimeSpanString(time, now, minResolution, flags);
}
```

From this it would appear that passing in `DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE | DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_MONTH` as the fourth parameter to `getRelativeTimeSpanString` would solve your problem.